# linux find command is not working properly

Tags: linux

I am using Linux(Ubuntu), I am trying to find the files, but it is not working properly.
I have created some files in my directory structure, for example: `World/India/Maharashtra/Pune/filename.xml`

When I use the find command like:

```
find /home/lokesh/Desktop/Testing_India2/Test/World/India/Maharashtra/ -name filename*.xml -mmin -3000
```

It is giving the result perfectly.

But, when I am using the same command at "World" or "India" level:

```
find /home/lokesh/Desktop/Testing_India2/Test/World/ -name filename*.xml -mmin -3000
```

it does not give any result.

I have lots of directories at "India" level as well as at "Maharashtra" level and may be some directories within "Maharashtra's" inner directories. I have to find each file created in all directories. 
And I have mounted all folders from different machine.(I mean some state from different and some from different machine.)

If someone knows how to solve this problem please reply me as soon as possible.

Comment: This is not a programming question and off topic here. I suggest you ask on http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Double quote your search string and `-L` to make it follow symbolic links:

```
find -L /home/lokesh/Desktop/Testing_India2/Test/World/ -name "filename*.xml" -mmin -30000
```

Comment: hi, thank for reply. I have tried same but it also not working. please suggest me if there are another way.

Comment: Try removing -mmin -3000 part.

Comment: I have also tried the same but not working. Is there any wrong in my find command.

Comment: I have tried to find by quote the search string, but not working. Can you answer me why it is working at directory level where the files are created?

Comment: Try searching like `find -D stat` to debug.

Comment: it is working but it give only directory not the file within it.

Comment: Thats interesting I guess permissions on the directories might be wrong. Are you able to `cd` into them as a user?

Comment: no permission is right. And I am also able to cd into them. If I tried "find -D stat" command on desktop it is giving all the file on desktop as well as the files within all the directory which is located on desktop. But if I tried it at world directory it give result as only directory within the world not the files inside it.

Comment: Looks like world directory is having some permission problems, please double check. Also there might be symbolic links there?

Comment: yes there are linking with all directory but it does not have any permission problem.

Comment: it giving "find: unknown predicate `-L'"

Comment: -L must be just after find like `find -L` can you try like that?

Comment: if I put -L after "find" it does not give any result.

Comment: hi, thanks. it working properly. can you tell me what happen if we put -L after find.

Comment: It also follows `symbolic links`.

Answer (score 4):

This is something I ran into earlier today actually when using the '*' wildcard.  I couldn't get it to continually traverse the subdirectories unless I escaped the * with a .

Give this a try:

```
find -L /home/lokesh/Desktop/Testing_India2/Test/World/ -name filename\*.xml -mmin -30000
```

Comment: The problem here is mentioned in the man page, that the shell expands the *, so you have to quote or escape it to avoid the shell expansion. Oh, and also in @KlausCPH 's answer below. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as mentioned you have to double qoute your `-name` argument or use a backslash prior to the `*`. The reason for it not working from one directory, but working fine in other directories, is that the `*` character is used for filename generation by your shell. This of course happens before the `find` command is executed. Therefore, if you have a file that match the `filename*.xml` pattern in your current directory it will be substituted before `find` is executed, which is not what you want. On the other hand, if there is no pattern match in the current directory, the `*` character is passed on to the find command unmodified. By qouting you protect the string from shell filename generation.

Regards